# Android Studio: how to increase the auto line wrap in the editor

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I edited this question to include the Flutter community, cause a lot of you use Android Studio and if anyone knows the answer, it'll be one of you. Thanks.

The editor in Android Studio is auto wrapping lines at about 80 characters.

How can I increase this? (using version 4.0)

Cheers,

Paul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Settings > Editor > Code Style > [Language] > Wrapping and Braces > Hard wrap at

Android Studio (as with all IDEs built off of the IntelliJ platform) formats each language according to different specifications, so you will need to change this for all the languages you are using. The default is usually 100 and the max is 999

Comment: I knew it! 2 weeks with no answer. Put it out to the flutter community and it's answered in minutes. Thanks Jacob. Appreciate the help.